# Python reading in a file and parsing it to variables with whitespaces

Tags: python, parsing

I have a text file (Students.txt) i need to read into python and parse them into variables first_name, middle_name, last_name, student_id. The first few lines of the text file is as shows:

```
Last Name  Midle Name  First Name   Student ID  
----------------------------------------------
Howard     Joe          Moe         howar1m     
Howard                  Curly       howar1c     
Fine       Ken          Lary        fine1l
```

The code I've tried

```
f = open("Students.txt")
for line in f:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    last_name = fields[0]
```

Only works for last name, because if I try `fields[1]` for middle name, I get a "list index out of range" error. I've tried using `if not line.startswith('Middle Name'): continue`  but it doesn't recognize the column. 
             Does anyone have a better approach as to how to parse these into their respective variables?

Comment: It says "Midle Name" instead of "Middle Name" in the text you show here (note the missing "d"). If it also says "Midle Name" in your text file, that could be why your `if` statement fails.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use readlines(), and then loop over each line with skipping first 2 rows. Hence the code will look like

```
f = open("Student.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
print lines
for line in lines[2:]:
    fields = line.split()
    last_name = fields[0]
    middle_name = fields[1]
```